# How do you install and bundle GraphicsMagick in an Electron app?

Tags: imagemagick, electron, graphicsmagick

I'm building an electron app and I need [GraphicsMagick](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm). The documentation suggest that you have to download and install the program itself before using it with node.js. So just installing the npm package is not enough.

How do I do it then? Do I actually have to have my Electron app download binaries (or bundle it with binaries) and then install the program on the first app launch in order to be able to use it?

It doesn't even support CLI commands like for example ffmpeg does, so I cannot just bundle the binaries and execute commands like `gm.exe convert test.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say yes, you have to bundle the binaries together with your app, if you don't want to distribute your app via a package repository or require your user to install GraphicsMagick previously.

It does support CLI commands like `gm.exe convert test.jpg`. If your using electron-builder for packaging, you must add a configuration to prevent the binaries from being asar-packed:

```js
  "build": {
    "asarUnpack": [
      "path/to/your/GraphicsMagick/binary/**"
    ],
```

From electron you can call the program e.g. with

```js
const child_process = require('child_process')
child_process.execFile('relative/path/to/your/gm.exe', ['version'], 
 (error, stdout, stderr) => { 
   console.log(stdout) 
 } )
```

You can download the windows binaries e.g. from the [sourceforge host](https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/). After installing those binaries you have to copy the installed folder to your app.

Comment: Thanks, good advice about excluding binaries from packing. What about bundled images? Will they also become unreachable after packing?

Comment: Images packed in the asar will be available from electron APIs, while some functions still end up in electron unpacking the images to filesystem (https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/application-packaging.md#extra-unpacking-on-some-apis). So you could use electron API to read the image from asar and pipe it via stdin to `gm.exe`. If passing the image as argument to `gm.exe /my/image` yes I guess the images must also be specified in `asarUnpack` or else gm.exe will fail extracting the image from asar.